# Is it okay in English to say to a cashier "Can you do me first?"

Tags: phrase-requests

Here is a situation: a person standing right in front of me in line reaches the cashier, but then suddenly recalls that he forgot one thing and leaves to take it, having said, "I'll be right back". However, he isn't back any time soon, while I only have one chocolate bar in my hands. Can I ask the cashier, "Can you do me first?" or that will have a negative (sexual?) connotation?

Or what would be the right way of asking here than? "Can you key in me first?"?

Comment: Can you check me out now? To go through a check-out line.

Comment: The question is asking for ideas and suggestions, so it isn't really a question that has a right answer and is not a good fit for the site. See: as well as “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity)”.

Comment: @MetaEd - "The question is asking for ideas and suggestions, so it isn't really a question that has a right answer" - The main question is in the very title, and it is "Is it okay to say so in English?" asking about some possible connotations of one particular English phrase spoken in one particular context. And as for the "ideas and suggestions", they are being asked about only in the very last line of the quesion, which doesn't change the nature of the main question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either say to the cashier, “Can you [ring me up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ring%20up) first?” or say to the person in front of you, “Can I go ahead of you?” The latter request is much more seemly. “Can you do me first?” *could* have venereal connotations.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with saying "Can you do me first?"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do

The definition of "do"

do verb (PERFORM):
"to perform, take part in, or achieve something"
meaning

Can you - perform your cashier services - on me, as your question would be directed towards the situation at hand.

-

BUT, the real question here would actually be - would another phrase be more correct in this situation?

With modern 'slang' "Do me" would be "perform on me" as rap and/or modern dictionary concatenates multiple sentences into single word phrases and change the meaning and context.

Where "did you do him/her?" would then be translated to "did you perform on him/her" and when you in a slang sense combine that with sexually loaded content that is automatically not the phrase you would choose for your local cashier.

"May i?"

"May i move ahead?"

"May i cut in line?"

"Can i go first?"

The above examples are more "on topic" or with context that explains the purpose of your request.

"Can you do me?" would be more of a "can you as a person assist me with something, undefined lacking an accurate description"

Finally, the cashier is already there to "do" her job, you have no need to confirm that in your question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80396/discussion-on-answer-by-juksefantomet-is-it-okay-in-english-to-say-to-a-cashier).

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives...

> "Do you want to serve me first?" or 
>  "Do you want to serve me
>   while he's getting his stuff?" or  "in the meantime."
>  "Should I go first?"

And hold up your chocolate bar for all to see.

If anyone thinks of something sexual when hearing "to do someone" it seems their head isn't in the right place. Of course it's alright. You can simply "do" people whether it be serving them, styling their hair, or tucking them into bed; there's no reason this should be an innuendo for something sexual unless utterer or hearer specifically has this disposition or mentality.

Plus, I would care less about making some minor faux pas with someone in a casual context. 0.1% of people will take offence, and if they do then the hell with them, they need to lighten up.

Also: "check me out" sounds really formal, like you're leaving a motel or clocking off from something. And "ring me up" I've never heard.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80465/discussion-on-answer-by-zebrafish-is-it-okay-in-english-to-say-to-a-cashier-can).